# $http.post setting requestHeader

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-http

How does:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "Service.asmx/GetChemicals", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
```

Translate to the angular controller? Right now I am doing:

```
var p = $http.post('Service.asmx/GetChemicals');
      p.success(function (data) {
          var settings = data;
          vm.stuff = JSON.parse(data);
      });
```

but my return data is not JSON format... It has the following:

```
 <xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"> data /string>
```

attached to it and I don't want to regex it out if I can just set the `requestheader` to JSON?

Comment: The tag `angularjs` is for angular 1.x. `angular` is for angular 2/4 and later.

Comment: It depends on your server, `asmx` services usually return everything as `soap` (ie XML).

Comment: Angular sends "Accept: application/json" request header by default. You should see that in your browser's developer tools network tab. If the server is returning XML regardless, that's an API contract issue.

Comment: The `$http.post` method takes three arguments: `url`, `data`, and `config`. The `config` argument is optional. JavaScript data objects are automatically encoded to JSON strings. The default content type header is set to `application/json`. For more information see [AngularJS $http Service API Reference ($http.post)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post).